# Find the general solution of first-order differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have $xy*dy/dx + 3y^2 -x^2 = 0,  x>0$.

Then,

$y' + 3y/x - x/y = 0$

I can not go on cause it is not linear.

What can I do next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
xy\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} + 3y^2 -x^2 = 0 \\
$$
Divide throughout by $x^2$
$$
\frac{y}{x}\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} + 3\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)^2-1 = 0 \\
\text{Take $u = \frac{y}{x}$} \\
u\left(u + x\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\mathrm{d}x}\right) + 3u^2-1 = 0 \\
ux\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\mathrm{d}x} + 4u^2-1 = 0 \\
ux\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\mathrm{d}x} = 1-4u^2 \\
\frac{u}{1-4u^2}\mathrm{d}u = \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x} \\
$$
I believe you can take it from here.

Answer (score 0):

Divide both sides by x, and then set u = y^2, then we have:

0.5u' + (3/x)*u = x ===> u' + (6/x)*u = 2x ===> (u*x^6)' = 2x^7 ===> u*x^6 = 1/4*x^8 + C

===> u = 1/4*x^2 + C/x^6

===> y^2 = 1/4*x^2 + C/x^6

===> y = (0.25x^2 + C/x^6) , and y = -(0.25x^2 + C/x^6)

Comment: you missed y' when divide both sides by x

Answer (score 0):

This is a *homogeneous* first-order ODE, meaning that $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is a homogeneous function of $x$ and $y$. (A function $f$ of two variables $x$ and $y$ is homogeneous if it satisfies $f(cx, cy) = c^nf(x, y)$ for all $c$ and some fixed $n$. $n$ is the *degree* of $f$.) When this is the case, substituting $u = x/y$ or $u = y/x$ will make the ODE separable. For more details, see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_differential_equation#Homogeneous_type_of_first-order_differential_equations) and maybe the section above it.